# How to test a private function inside an RxSwift observer?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, quick-nimble, rxtest

```
observable.subscribe(onNext: { _ in
    somePrivateFunction()
})
```

What is the RxSwift way to test that when `observable` receives an event the `somePrivateFunction` actually gets called or not? Since the subscription and the function are in the same class I can't mock it.

Comment: The RxSwift library has an entire battery of tests to ensure that Observables work correctly. Including tests to ensure that when an observable emits a next event, the `onNext` closure gets called. If you want to test the RxSwift library, itself then I suggest you refer to those tests... However, I suspect that isn't what you are actually trying to test. Tells us what you really want to ensure and maybe we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if any logic is placed in a subscription that can block call of this function. If there is - it may be worth to extract it to a parameter (eg. filter) so that logic can be a part of stream itself.

I assume that observable (source) is injected/redirected from another component (if it's not, most probably it should be). To mock that signal you can use `TestableObservable`, you can read more here: http://adamborek.com/rxtests-rxactionsheet/

Last but not least - you need to identify what kind of action `somePrivateFunction()` does. If it's setting some external values - then you can test that outgoing connection from that function. If it sets some internal flags - you can test if value of that flag has changed.